# Unable to start a Java/Lanterna program

Tags: java, linux, chef-infra, headless, lanterna

I'm currently writing a small terminal application, using what I find a very cool Java library : [Lanterna](http://code.google.com/p/lanterna/). it allows me to write ncurses-like application using similar concepts to Swing.

As that application ultumate goal is to be run on servers, I test it on a Vagrant ubuntu box. Unfortunatly, at each start-up, I get the following error :

```
vagrant@precise64:~/myProject/target$ java -jar myProject-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -Djava.awt.headless=true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/lib/amd64/xawt/libmawt.so: libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1807)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1703)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:770)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1003)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1807)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1724)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
        at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:50)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1605)
        at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1627)
        at java.awt.Font.<clinit>(Font.java:210)
        at com.googlecode.lanterna.terminal.swing.TerminalAppearance.createDefaultNormalFont(TerminalAppearance.java:46)
        at com.googlecode.lanterna.terminal.swing.TerminalAppearance.<clinit>(TerminalAppearance.java:33)
        at com.googlecode.lanterna.terminal.swing.SwingTerminal.<init>(SwingTerminal.java:77)
        at com.googlecode.lanterna.TerminalFacade.createSwingTerminal(TerminalFacade.java:115)
        at com.googlecode.lanterna.TerminalFacade.createSwingTerminal(TerminalFacade.java:104)
        at com.googlecode.lanterna.TerminalFacade.createTerminal(TerminalFacade.java:95)
        at com.googlecode.lanterna.TerminalFacade.createTerminal(TerminalFacade.java:65)
        at com.googlecode.lanterna.TerminalFacade.createTerminal(TerminalFacade.java:54)
        at com.googlecode.lanterna.TerminalFacade.createScreen(TerminalFacade.java:247)
        at com.googlecode.lanterna.TerminalFacade.createGUIScreen(TerminalFacade.java:261)
```

I guess there is a problem with my Java installation, which come from the [Chef solo](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Chef+Solo) [Java](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/java) recipe using this configuration

```
    chef.json = {
        :java => {
            :install_flavor => "oracle",
            :oracle => {
                "accept_oracle_download_terms" => true
            }               
        },
        :maven => {
            :version => '3',
            :setup_bin => 'true'
        }
    }
```

But how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

libXtst.so comes with a package named: [libxtst6](http://packages.debian.org/sid/libxtst6) ; than is in debian. Check if that package is installed, maybe chef does not install that package automatically .

Good-luck

Comment: +1: I've hit this before on Debian. libxst6 was one of the things you needed. Once you install it, you might end up having to install a few more libraries, if this is Debian.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the fact that my ssh session has - as a default - a X forwarding set ... which may lead to that crazy behaviouor ...

Comment: I'll accept your answer even if not totally correct for the simple reason you lead me to the correct conclusion. It seems that the Java recipe installs a headless version of Java, of course without X support. As a consequence running an application that starts a swing UI if needed fails if application is in context supposed to support Swing (which is the case when X forwarding is enabled).